# Error in GeoGebra-Generated Tikz Code

Tags: tikz-pgf, geogebra

I used GeoGebra 5.0.0 to draw a diagram consisting of a few points, lines, and circles inverted in a circle (it's called `reflection in a circle' in GeoGebra). I then exported the graphics view to PGF/Tikz, which gave me some Tikz code. I copied the code into a separate LaTeX file which I include in my main LaTeX file.

The MWE is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{wwqqcc}{rgb}{0.4,0.,0.8}
\definecolor{qqqqcc}{rgb}{0.,0.,0.8}
\definecolor{ffqqtt}{rgb}{1.,0.,0.2}
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0.,0.39215686274509803,0.}
\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49019607843137253,0.49019607843137253,1.}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0.,0.,1.}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45,x=0.38cm,y=0.38cm]
\draw [shift={(8.670843563481125,-1.625382794581949)},color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) -- (92.14755363945639:0.6416494992173465) arc (92.14755363945639:193.5659068943232:0.6416494992173465) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(and then many similar lines with different constants also give the same error). The error itself is

> Package calc Error: `.' invalid at this point

The words 'this point' in the error refer to this part of the code:

```
(92.14755363945639:0.6416494992173465) arc (92.14755363945639:193.5659068943232:0.6416494992173465)
```

Note: I am completely inexperienced with Tikz on its own because I always draw in GeoGebra and export to Tikz, so please explain what you are doing if you are giving me any different Tikz code.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @MaartenDhondt is that enough? Thanks!

Comment: @shardulc together with the `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}`, your code compiles just fine for me. No errors here.

Comment: Both your code here and on gist works without any problems. If you add `\pgfversion` on your document, make sure that you have version 3.0 and not 2.10

Comment: @percusse Oh dear, it prints out 1.10! I will update my PGF/Tikz and either update my question or delete it. Do I need to update anything else or will the dependencies take care of it for me?

Comment: Wow take it to a museum and get rich :P The best thing to do is to update your TeX distribution completely, whether it is TeX Live(latest for your linux) or MikTeX (v2.9).

Comment: No luck at the museum, they said I need to bring original copies signed in triplicate. The latest TeX Live for Fedora is from 2012, version 2.10, but it seems to be working all right. Thanks! (BTW what is the standard protocol now? Do I delete the question?)

Comment: You can vote for off-topic. I'll write up a reason now. It will add an auto-comment below this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is a no-repro after updating the TeX distro.